# Method could not be resolved

Tags: c++, oop, methods

In my header file:

```
Esame();
Esame(string);
Esame(string, Voto);
```

This is a c++ tester class:

```
//OK
Esame esame("Algoritmi e strutture dati", 30);
esame.stampaEsame();

//OK
Esame esame2("Metodi Avanzati di Programmazione");
esame2.setVoto(26);
esame2.stampaEsame();

//ERROR 
Esame esame3();
esame3.setVoto(26); //Method could not be resolved
esame3.stampaEsame(); //Method could not be resolved
```

The code doesn't compile at all. Why it doesn't find the method if the object has been created with the same class in the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`esame3()` does'nt call a default constructor. In your case the compiler is thinking that you have declared a **method**

It should be

`Esame esame3;`

**OR**

`Esame esame3=Esame();`

Using `new` to create an object would create an object that would be allocated dynamically..

In that case your class would have to be a `pointer` like this

`Esame *esame3=new Esame;`

You would have to use `->` instead of `.` to access member method or variables..

```
esame3->method1();
esame3->varable1;
```

Comment: Your second example `Esame esame3=Esame()` contradicts what you mean with your first sentence.

Comment: You're saying "`Esame()` does'nt call a default constructor" but it does (in the example you posted).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore i wanted it to be an object not class.. `esame3`..;)

Comment: what if you want create the object using "new"?

Comment: Sorry I switched to C++ from Java: there we do Esame esame3= new Esame(). From what you said you cannot use new operator to create an object of that class.

Comment: @Hoconosc I did not say that. I said you can and they are optional (meaning you can either use them or not)

Comment: Perfect, I was using the dot notation instead of -> . Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Esame esame3();` is a function declaration. `esame3` doesn't name an object in this case. It declares a function called `esame3` that takes no parameters and returns an object of type `Esame`.

This is called the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

To create an object using the default constructor, use `Esame esame3;` (no parenthesis):

```
Esame esame3;
esame3.setVoto(26); 
esame3.stampaEsame();
```

Comment: Great, it worked. Just another related question: What if I wanted to create an object of Esame class using new keyword?

Comment: @Hoconosc in that context, you can use parenthesis (they are optional), but that's because it couldn't be treated as a declaration.